# FullCalendar - Can I achieve this view (see images)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

I have downloaded and been experimenting with FullCalendar and it does *almost* everything I need for a resource scheduling app I am developing for my company's use.  I just need to try and get it to display the events a bit differently and was hoping someone might be able to help.

I currently have it configured to display like this:

[image]

However, I am ultimately need it to display like this (side by side):

[image]

This is for a sequential process and it is important to convey the order of events and if one event (blue) extends into another day then the next day's event(s) (purple) have to wait until that one is done.  This is not as clear in the top image as the bottom one.

Is this something that can be configured or will this require me to modify the source or intercept the event render and manipulate it there?

Thanks!

[EDIT] Added code snippets:

TEMPLATE:

```
<FullCalendar ref="fullCalendar"
          default-view="resourceTimelineMonth"
          :plugins="calendarPlugins"
          :events="calEvents"
          :resources="calResources"
          :weekends="true"
          :editable="true"
          :event-overlap="false"
          :slot-width="100"/>
```

SCRIPT:

```
data () {
  return {
    ...
    calendarPlugins: [ interactionPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin ],
    calEvents: [
        { resourceId: "101", title: 'WO123', start: '2019-11-01T07:00:00', end: '2019-11-01T12:00:00', backgroundColor: 'red' },
        { resourceId: "101", title: 'WO127', start: '2019-11-01T12:00:00', end: '2019-11-01T18:00:00', backgroundColor: 'green'  },
        { resourceId: "101", title: 'WO144', start: '2019-11-01T18:00:00', end: '2019-11-02T03:00:00', backgroundColor: 'blue'  },
        { resourceId: "101", title: 'WO145', start: '2019-11-02T03:00:00', end: '2019-11-02T10:00:00', backgroundColor: 'purple'  }
    ],
    calResources: [
        {id: "101", title: "KM101"},
        {id: "102", title: "KM102"},
        {id: "103", title: "KM103"},
        {id: "104", title: "KM104"},
        {id: "105", title: "KM105"},
      ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show the actual event data you're using to get the current display? And the calendar config code please? It may just be that you need to set a smaller slotDuration so you get sufficient granularity in the display for the events to appear in sequence. Right now you seem only to have a granularity of one whole day, so inevitably it's going to be difficult to see specific times within that

Comment: Thanks.  I added the salient code snippets to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I hinted at in the comments above, the reason you don't see what you're hoping for is because when you compress each slot to a single day, fullCalendar appears to switch to an "all-day" mode of display, where it ceases to take the specific times of day into account, and simply indicates the day(s) in which the event occurs.

The way to get a display the way (or close to the way) you want is to reduce the slot duration to half a day (which clearly creates the least division of the day you can do), and also modify the slot labels slightly to suit. Once the slot duration involves hours, fullCalendar will start taking the time component of the event into account again when it renders.

I don't know vue.js syntax and can't make a demo of it, so I've done the code and demo below in vanilla JS, but hopefully you can translate that into the syntax used by the vue plugin without any difficulty.

Options to add to your calendar config:

```
slotDuration: { hours: 12 },
slotLabelFormat: [
  { weekday: "short" },
  { hour: "2-digit", },
],
```

Live demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/VwwXowr

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-display for relevant documentation.

Comment: Perfect!!  Thanks so much for your help!